# Cannot set member variable to null

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, weblogic12c

I would really like to provide a minimal working example for this question, but I did not succeed in creating one. So I'll just describe what's happening and hope that someone can be of help anyway.

Somewhere in my code, I have these lines:

```
long i = 0;
while (this.someField != null) {
    this.someField = null;
    i++;
}
long j = i;
```

(This code is the result of lots of debugging I have already done to find the cause of my problem.)

This code is deployed on a WebLogic Application server. I have a breakpoint set just before the `while` loop. I debug the code remotely with IntelliJ.

When the code hits the breakpoint, I execute it step-by-step. The code just keeps looping through the `while` loop, but `someField` never becomes `null`. So I set a second breakpoint at the line after the loop, and hit *continue*. The code immediately exits the loop and stops at this line. I can tell that there are no more executions of the loop because I inspect `i` afterwards. However, `this.someField` *still* isn't null. I tried it multiple times, so I am quite sure that the reason why the code keeps executing the loop is that I am debugging it.

I have no idea how to debug this problem. My observations just don't make any sense (unless I apply quantum mechanics). What could cause such behavior? Is this a bug in my JVM? A bug in the debugger? Something else?

Edit:

The field is declared like this:

```
 private Vector<KeyValuePair> someField = null;
```

It is private and I ensured that is is not changed by another thread by setting breakpoints on all methods that mangle with it.

Comment: Any chance concurrency is part of the mystery? Can you show the definition of `someField`?

Comment: There are other threads on the application server, but they're all running in different deployments and cannot possibly interfere with this object.

Comment: I think you need to try harder to produce a minimal example. At the moment your question is impossible to answer, and it's not clear why you need a `while` loop to set a field to `null`.

Comment: I am perfectly aware that I should not need the `while` loop. I just added it because I was baffled about the field not becoming `null` after a normal assignment.

Comment: The chance might be small but since it happend to me as well I'll ask anyways: Are you 100% sure that the code which is running on the server is the very same your debugger sees? Are you sure the server is set up to isolate deployments? Are you sure there's no reflection code that accessed the field?

Comment: I did decompile the `.class` with IntelliJ and it showed the same code as I have here. I also inserted a function call at the position of the while loop and redeployed just to make sure that redeployment does deploy the code I see. The function got called, so I am pretty sure the code I see is actually the one deployed on the machine.

Comment: A colleague speculated that when I stop the step-by-step-debugging, the JIT compiler optimizes the `while`-loop away and that's why I get to the line behind it. Could that be possible? It wouldn't explain while the field doesn't become null though.

Comment: May be a silly question, but do you do you have any expression in debug mode that sets someField to a value? if Yes, the object would be set to some value on every turn, but at least that would explain why you have this issue.

Comment: How do you know the field is not null after the loop? Is it only the debugger telling you this, or do you have other confirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the IntelliJ debugger. The debugger sets the value while debugging, and the control flow changes according to this modification. When I used the Eclipse debugger instead, the problem vanished.